# Execute script located inside linked volume on host environment

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have some scripts (script1.sh, script2.sh) located inside my node based container (linked by volume).

Those scripts are located at /var/www/myproject/cmd (inside container).

**IMPORTANT**: the scripts are located inside a linked folder

I triggered them with nodejs spawn function:

```
spawn( './cmd/script1.sh', [ '.' ] )
```

Actually, they run inside container environment, but I want them to be executed inside the host environment. How can I achieve that?

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
    services:
    nodejs:
         image: my-node-image
         volumes:
            - ./cmd:/var/www/myproject/cmd
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your use case,  why would you use a container then?
Simply run the script on the host machine and avoid the unneeded container :\
If the node interpreter that runs is the one in the container you'll always get the same result.

Comment: I have other services inside docker-compose so I need to run nodejs inside docker

Comment: I should make my question clearer then - what is it that you want to achieve with this script that *must* run on the host machine?

Comment: You can’t, this is a primary design goal of Docker and (unlike many of the other Docker isolation mechanisms) you can’t easily circumvent it.